# Computer won't start even after clean Windows 10 install

Tags: windows-10

2 days ago, my laptop just stopped working. I left it working on the table for about 2 hours and when I got back, noticed it froze, tried to reboot it and it wouldn't start since then. When "lenovo" icon and that spinner appear, after some time, the spinner just stops.

Tried both system restore and system reset, both gave me some errors.

Then I tried reinstalling Windows. I made a boot USB drive, installed windows, everything went smoothly. Until windows installation gets to that "getting devices ready" part. Same again, spinner appears and stops. Tried reinstalling again, same happens. Maybe bad drivers are causing this? And since windows won't install, I can't get to safe mode or anything else.

So basically I now have a computer without windows, that can't install windows. What do you think is causing this problem? I can give further info if you need any. Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-3175489/windows-work-clean-reinstall.html already posted here, but got no answers.

Comment: Can you try another OS like Windows 7 or Ubuntu?

Comment: Boot from a Linux live CD/USB to make sure hardware is fine,

for example Ubuntu  or Knoppix: http://www.knoppix.org/

Answer (score 1):

Get to a recovery console with an installation disc to inspect your system. Try the following:

1. Check for disk errors with `chkdsk /f C:`
2. Rebuild Boot Configuration Data `bootrec /RebuildBCD`
3. Fix the Master Boot Record `bootrec /fixMbr`
4. Fix the boot sector `bootrec /fixboot`
5. Repair partitions `bootsect /nt60 ALL`

If you attempt to reinstall windows, verify the integrity of the disc.

P.S. It's a good idea to flash your BIOS with the latest firmware. Although rare, a tiny rootkit can install itself into the BIOS. Flashing with get rid of it. If you have the same version already, you may need to force flash it.

Comment: Has anyone ever seen a BIOS rootkit out of lab? I believe it's purely hypothetical threat, never observed in the wild.

Comment: Probably not, but they can be targeted directly at individuals which is something I've seen before.

Comment: I did steps 1-5, gonna post results. 1: windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. 2: successfully scanned windows installations. Total identified windows installations: 0.   3 and 4: the operation completed successfully. 5: C, D, E: successfully updated NTFS filesystem bootcode. F: could not open the volume root directory... After this tried rebooting and got BSOD with error code 0xc0000001, googled it, tried fixing and fixed nothing. I'm gonna try installing from another USB and flashing BIOS next. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Leonz You could try booting in safe mode to see if the issue persists. If it boots, then it's a driver issue. Otherwise, it may be a hardware issue or boot files are corrupted. At this point though, I would do the simple. Wipe out the disc with a full format (not a quick format), then attempt to install. If you get errors, it's probably a hardware issue.

Comment: I've tried something similar. I can't boot to safe mode since windows aren't installed on the laptop, but I downloaded Hirens Bootcd, which has "mini windows XP" on it, booted to that and it actually booted into those Windows. So it probably is driver issue. If you read this, could you please point me in the right direction, post a link or anything about how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Okay, since you have Hiren's BootCD, boot into *Linux based rescue environment*. Once it boots, you'll see "Disk Eraser" on the desktop. Open this icon. **This next step will completely wipe your drive!** If you have a traditional hard disk drive, choose the first option. If you have a solid state drive, choose the *internal* option. Choose your drive and run the program. Now boot up a Windows 10 installation disk and look at this post on how to install http://www.groovypost.com/howto/clean-install-Windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bad install ISO

This happened to me.

Id download an ISO through microsoft, and use your key. (will need account)

Comment: I did actually download it from Microsoft, from Media Creation Tool. I can try to burn it tomorrow again, but it was a legit install. Also, laptop came with windows installed so product key is "connected" to it (idk how to say it better). Also, when we're at it, I have access to free Windows 10 through Dreamworks, do you think I should try to install that one too?

Comment: @Leonz it's exactly the same thing, why waste a license, when you don't have to

Comment: YEah but the laptop Key is the OEM key which requires an OEM disk... which... hell if i remember. Frankly I run modded ISOs. (like Alien Black Ed and etc...) I cant officially "recommend" them - but... its what i run.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a Linux live CD/USB to make sure hardware is fine

for example Knoppix or Ubuntu

Comment: As a diagnostic suggestion rather than a solution, this would probably be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Could you please post the link to where I can find ISO for this? Also, hardware diagnostic can be made from USB boot directly, without installing Linux? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If doesn't boot from live Linux -> hardware issue, not Windows one. Proper diagnostics is part of the solution. Sounds like hardware issue and no matter how many times you re-install Windows it will be the same result